# Python only recognizing variables

Tags: python, variables

I have an "if" statement and yet it only recognizes what it equals as a variable.
Don't really know how to explain it very well but here's an example

```
a = input("Hello! What is your name?")                                                        
if a == Gabe_Newell :                                                                         
    print ("Hello, Gaben!")
```

Comment: Can you explain better? I do not understand.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to compare with a string:

```
a = input("Hello! What is your name?")
if a == "Gabe_Newell":
    print ("Hello, Gaben!")
```

this code works for python3, if using python2, write:

```
a = raw_input("Hello! What is your name?")
if a == "Gabe_Newell":
    print ("Hello, Gaben!")
```

I assume that you want to say `Hello, Gaben` when user input `Gabe_Nawell`